# Excel opens wrong view after generating in Apache POI

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

Currently I render an Excel file with some product relations (the first column is hidden).
These relations can be altered in Excel and then re-entered in my program.

If there are any errors (invalid data), we add an error in the first cell of the row and write it to the Excel file.

When I open that Excel file again (in Excel), the view shows every row from column B (second column).
The first row has some data however, is there any way I can force the view to start from A again?

Kind regards,

Niels

Comment: did you unhide the first column after adding the error-message? Adding text to a cell in a hidden column doesn't unhide it automatically.

Comment: I've tried to perform 'productSheet.setColumnHidden(0, false);' , but that didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it through the following code:

```
if (sheet instanceof XSSFSheet)
    {
        final CTWorksheet workSheet = ((XSSFSheet) sheet).getCTWorksheet();
        if (workSheet != null)
        {
            final CTSheetViews views = workSheet.getSheetViews();
            if (views != null)
            {
                if (views.getSheetViewArray(0) != null)
                {
                    views.getSheetViewArray(0).setTopLeftCell("A1");
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

After that, the view had reset. So when the Excel file was opened again, the top left cell was in focus and displayed.